# How to auto format and remove extra tabs and whitespace after copy pasting code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, clang

I switched from Eclipse to VS Code for my Java coding but now Ive just spent an entire day trying to get VS Code to format my Java code correctly.

I tried RedHat's Language Support for Java Extension, but this didnt work.
Next I tried clang, which now formats my code as intended most of the time, however having it format away/remove these pesky extra tabs/whitespace after a copy paste job has been the bane of my day...

A picture says a thousand words:
[image]

No matter what clang formatting options I try, I just cannot get rid of these extra unwanted tabs/whitespace...

Please help.

Even if I have to switch to a different formatter solution instead of clang ill happily do that, I just want my java code to format the same way as my C# code... which automagically removes these tabs/whitespace for me by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl + k + f` By keeping the ctrl key pressed after selecting all content. this should solved your issue. Check this for more [details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics).

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse button and select `Format Document`, or use the shortcut `Shift+Alt+F` to format the code.

[image]

You can also use the command `Java: Open Java Formatter with Preview` to open the java extended formatting settings, where you can customize the formatting effect.

[image]